# How to set indexpath.row = i

Tags: uitableview

```
- (void)checkSelected:(NSMutableArray *)dataUser
{
    NSNumber * number = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"treatment"];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < dataUser.count; i++)
    {
        Treatment *treatment = (Treatment *)[dataUser objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([treatment.treatment_id isEqualToNumber:number])
        {
            NSIndexPath *indexpath = nil;
            //indexpath.row = i;
            DLog(@"index path:%d",indexpath.row);
            TreatementUserCell *cell = (TreatementUserCell*) [self.treatementUserTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
            if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark ) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                UIImageView *image= [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pick.png"]];
                cell.accessoryView = image;

            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set indexPath.row = i, but indexPath is readonly. How do I set it?

Comment: Couldn't understand what you are saying ,could you please arrange the code.

Comment: Like other immutable classes, you need to create a new instance with the values you need.

Answer (score 0):

Read the NSIndexPath documentation to discover the method `indexPathForRow:inSection:`.

Comment: More correctly it's the `UIKit` category for `NSIndexPath`

Comment: @rmaddy but the NSIndexPath class doc points you to it. I checked.

Comment: Yes but it may not be obvious that you need to click on that link at the end of the note at the end of the Overview section just to get to the other part of the docs for `NSIndexPath` just to find what you need. At least not for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

`NSIndexPath` contains `Rows` and `Sections`, Try this code to assign value for `NSIndexPath`

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection: section];
```